# CANOpen SDO block transfer retry if timeouted?

Tags: can, protocol, error-correction, canopen

I'm using the CanFestival CANOpen library (https://canfestival.org/) for a PC app that talks to a device via CAN bus. The device is CIA-301 compliant. I'm using SDO block transfers for device firmware upgrades. It occurred to me that sometimes the last segment (with index 0x7F) of a 127*7-byte block is lost during FW read (SDO upload transfer). If I understand correctly this last segment is absolutely necessary because otherwise, the client cannot send an ACK with the report of received segments. If some segment in the middle of the block is lost it is noted in the report, but it seems the 0x7F segment must always be received otherwise the entire SDO upload transfer just fails with a timeout. I find it hard to believe that such a shortcoming exists in the standard.

My question is, can I add retries in case of SDO timeouts, or is it against the CIA-301 ? Retries of an entire transfer are also quite time costly, I would prefer some other solution, but currently, I don't see any other option. What is the typical error recovery procedure in case if 0x7F segment is lost?

Comment: Even where the standard provides sufficient information for retrying a single block, it doesn't mandate it, and most devices do not implement it.  Also, where do you get "127-byte block" from?  The block size is (bytes per segment) * (number of segments per block).

Comment: Are you claiming that the client can't detect a problem, or that it is not allowed to "send an ACK with the report of received segments" when it does detect a problem?

Comment: The client waits for the last segment to be received inside a block before it sends a report to the server.

Comment: And are you assuming that some other device on the bus, not the intended destination of these SDO block transfers, is ACK-ing data not sent to it?  Because if the CAN datagram isn't ACKed (the datagram ACK, not the higher application-level block transfer ACK datagram), the sender immediately detects the problem.

Comment: This device and the CAN dongle are the only nodes present on CAN bus.

Comment: "The client waits for the last segment to be received inside a block before it sends a report to the server"  That sounds like your design decision rather than a protocol requirement.  If the client sends an selective ACK datagram requesting retry after half the total timeout has elapsed, there's no problem, is there?

Comment: "This device and the CAN dongle are the only nodes present on CAN bus"  Then the sender will immediately detect transmission failure and retry the transmission without need for a selective ACK datagram or a timeout (there may be backoff to reduce the chance of collision)

Comment: "The client waits for the last segment to be received inside a block before it sends a report to the server" it's how the CanFestival library works.

Comment: "it's how the CanFestival library works" Then blame the library, not the standard.  But in your two-node network, it's unlikely to be a problem, because the failure is detected at the datalink layer due to missing ACK of the CAN frame.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Base_frame_format

Comment: Seems you are asking the wrong question. Why are you even losing packages on a bus where you are alone, would be the far more relevant one. Given that the retry functionality already exists on the data link layer and the node will keep trying until it goes error passive. Are you getting error frames or what? You need to clarify why you are losing packages to begin with.